# Getting an empty div when using <ReactSVG>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I'm trying to create a reusable icon component in React that takes the name of an SVG icon and renders it.

I'm using `<ReactSVG>` component to render SVG files

**Icon.jsx**

This component takes in 2 props - **className** and **name**. The **name** prop is used in the `src` attribute to obtain the correct SVG file.

```
import { ReactSVG } from "react-svg";

const Icon = ({ className, name }) => {
  return <ReactSVG src={`../../../assets/icons/${name}.svg`} className={className} />;
};

export default Icon;
```

And here's how I'm **using the Icon component** in my **nav component**

```
import Icon from '../base/icon/icon.component.jsx';

const navLinks = [
  { title: 'Home', icon: 'home' },
  { title: 'Profile', icon: 'user' },
  { title: 'Settings', icon: 'settings' }
];

const Nav = () => {
  return (
    <nav>
      {navLinks.map((navLink) => (
        <div key={navLink.title}>
          <Icon className={navLink.icon} name={navLink.icon} />
          <span>{navLink.title}</span>
        </div>
      ))}
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Nav;
```

This is my **folder structure**

```
--src
  |-- assets
  |    |-- icons
  |    |    |-- home.svg
  |-- components
  |    |-- base
  |    |    |-- icon
  |    |    |    |-- icon.jsx
  |    |-- nav
  |    |    |-- nav.jsx
```

I'm not getting any errors but I can't see the Icon either.
When I inspect in the browser, I see an **empty `div`** like this: `<div class="home"></div>` instead of the icon

Could anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? or even give me an alternate method to achieve what I'm trying to do

Comment: From your folder structure, as the component is inside the base folder, you need to go up one more level using ../../ to get to the assets folder. {`../../assets/icons/${name}.svg`}

Comment: Thanks @dostogircse171, but it didn't work. Just for reference, I tried this: {`../../../../assets/icons/${name}.svg`} and this {`../../assets/icons/${name}.svg`}

Comment: Did you try to debug the app using "React Developer Tools"? Can you see any error/warning there?

Comment: @dostogircse171, I tried it now. I don't see any errors or warning there.